# Getting 403 error code while testing http url of mysite using test script

Tags: http, apache2.4

I'm getting 403 error code while testing http urls of mysite using test script. But while access in browser, works fine. Please help to fix the problem. Testing other site urls using the test script, provides 200 status code

Comment: if you can, check the `.htaccess` file.
and try again after delete that file

Comment: There is no .htaccess file and using centos